# python json.dumps()’s data is contain \, how to clean it

Tags: python, json

```
def getJson(filmList):
film_json = FilmJson()
for video in filmList:
    videoName = video.videoName
    videoUrl = video.videoUrl
    videoTime = video.videoTime
    dic = {}
    if videoName is None:
        break

    if videoUrl is None:
        dic['videourl'] = ""
    else:
        dic['videourl'] = videoUrl


    if videoTime is None:
        dic['videotime'] = ""
    else:
        dic['videotime'] = videoTime
    dic['videoname'] = videoName


    film_json.videolist.append(dic)

dict__ = film_json.__dict__
print(dict__)

return dict__
```

The browser send get request

the backend print

```
{'filmid': '', 'videolist': [{'videourl': '', 'videotime': '', 'videoname': 'Lifeline'}, {'videourl': '', 'videotime': '', 'videoname': 'Ex Static'}, {'videourl': '', 'videotime': '', 'videoname': 'test'}]}
```

.

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def sendFilm(request):
   ....
    myjson = jsonbean.getJson(filmList)



    return Response(json.dumps(myjson,ensure_ascii=False))
```

The postman test get result

```
"{\"filmid\": \"\", \"videolist\": [{\"videourl\": \"\", \"videotime\": \"\", \"videoname\": \"Lifeline\"}, {\"videourl\": \"\", \"videotime\": \"\", \"videoname\": \"Ex Static\"}, {\"videourl\": \"\", \"videotime\": \"\", \"videoname\": \"test\"}]}"
```

how to resolve the  problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encoding a JSON object again to JSON using json.dumps(). If you use json.loads() again then the \'s will go away.

```
return Response(json.loads(json.dumps(myjson,ensure_ascii=False)))
#OR
return Response(myjson)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have double dumped.

You just need to json.dumps() once. This error happens because you've json.dumps() on an object that is already a JSON.

`return Response( myjson )` should return a regular object without the `\"`.

Since `myjson` is already a JSON string and not a dictionary object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `json.dumps` when passing the data to Response.